# Class 'AWeberAPI' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, aweber

I got no clue why AWeberAPI is not found. Any help is appreciated.

php code:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
new PHPExcel;
new AWeberAPI;
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aweber/aweber": "^1.1",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

The module doesn't appear to be properly configured for use/autoloading with composer. They may have just added the composer configuration to allow you to easily install it, but not to use it within the composer autoloader.

The generic convention for it is that `AWeberAPI` should match the package's PSR-4 autoloader format, which says "look in aweber_api", then it will look for a class named `AWeberAPI.php`. You can test this behaviour is correct by adding this file:

```
<?php
// File: vendor/aweber/aweber/aweber_api/AWeberAPI.php
class AWeberAPI {
    public function __construct() {
        die('yeah, it works now...');
    }
}
```

Then try your script again, the class will exist now.

---

### What can I do?

Well - you *could* submit a pull request to their repository to fix it, but it looks like it would involve renaming the classes and filenames which would be a breaking change so I probably wouldn't bother.

You can get it to work by requiring the actual source of the API library instead of the composer autoloader in this case:

```
require_once 'vendor/aweber/aweber/aweber_api/aweber_api.php';
```

Comment: oh ok. My next plan is to include it in laravel. Do you have suggestion how I can require the api neatly? btw thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't used Laravel before. You could probably get away with including the source file itself as in that last example. Otherwise you may need to submit a pull request for a "composer friendly" class alias.